# Consequence of Peter-Weyl theorem

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, representation-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}$ denote the torus $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. It follows from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem (or from basic results in Fourier analysis) that the span of functions of the form $e^{2\pi i  n x}$, with $n\in\mathbb Z$, is uniformly dense in $C(\mathbb T)$. I think this result can be extended to (continuous) actions of $\mathbb T$ on compact metric spaces: Suppose $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space and $\mathbb T$ acts continuously on $X$. Consider the set $\mathcal A_X$ consisting of all functions $f\in C(X)$ for which there exists some $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $$ f(tx)=e^{2\pi i k t}f(x),~~\forall t\in\mathbb T,~\forall x\in X.$$
I believe that the span of $\mathcal A_X$ is dense in $C(X)$ with respect to uniform convergence, but I am not entirely sure how to prove this fact. In particular, I'm not sure why the algebra $\mathcal A_X$ separates points (because if it does, then Stone-Weierstrass finishes the proof.)

**Question 1:** Why is the span of $\mathcal A_X$ dense in $C(X)$?

Now, instead of just $\mathbb T$, let us consider the more general case where $G$ is an arbitrary compact topological group.
A *matrix coefficient* of G is a complex-valued function φ on G given as the composition

$$\displaystyle \varphi =\ell (\pi(g)(v))$$

where $π : G → GL(\mathbb C^n)$ is a finite-dimensional (continuous) group representation of $G$, $v\in\mathbb C^n$ and $\ell$ is a linear functional on $\mathbb C^n$.
The first part of the Peter–Weyl theorem asserts that the set of matrix coefficients of $G$ is dense in $C(G)$.

For my 2nd question, suppose that $G$ acts continuously on a compact metric space$(X,d)$.
Let $\mathcal B_X$ denote the set of all functions $f\in C(X)$ for which there exists some matrix coefficient $\varphi$ such that
$$ f(gx)=\varphi(g)f(x),~~\forall g\in G,~\forall x\in X.$$

**Question 2:** Is $\mathcal B_X$ dense in $C(X)$?

The answer to question 2 would be "yes" if one could show (with the help of the Peter-Weyl theorem) that $\mathcal B_X$ seperates points, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Given a topological dynamical system $(X, d, \mathbb T)$ you are asking why the span of the continuous eigenfunctions are dense in $C(X)$.  But I think that this is not always dense. If I am not mistaken there exists such dynamical systems for which all eigenfunctions are discontinuous. Also, I think that the claim is not true if the pure point dynamical spectrum is trivial.

Comment: should integrate the action so you can apply a function on the group to  an element